# Stop Selenium 3.0.1 using command line

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I tryied command from older versions, but it dont seems to work.

```
curl "http://localhost:5555/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer"
```

Answer (score 3):

'Old' command is not working because it's part of selenium RC which is not included in selenium 3.

You should now start your nodes with `-servlet org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.LifecycleServlet` included, and than you can shut it down with `http://yourNodeIP:port/extra/LifecycleServlet?action=shutdown`

I reported this issue few months ago and it's solved so you can check it out for more details here. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2982

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux you can kill the process running on that port by

```
fuser -k 5555/tcp
```

or netstat -plten |grep java you will get the PID of seleniumserver process.

```
kill -9 PID.
```

Also try hitting the lifecycle of selenium grid2

```
http://yourHubIP:port/lifecycle-manager?action=shutdown
```

CTRL+c from your terminal also would help.

let me know if you are looking for anything else

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running it on *nix and the standalone server is listening on the default port (4444)... you need to:

- find the PID of the process that is bound to port 4444 (use `lsof` command)
- send that process a SIGTERM to gracefully shutdown (use the `kill` command)

you can achieve this with the following one-liner:

```
$ lsof -t -i :4444 | xargs kill
```